# How to link the specific application.properties files based on Maven profile

Tags: java, maven, configuration, maven-profiles, application.properties

I have a plain Java project with several property files (for several environments):

```
application.properties
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
```

where:

- `application.properties` is saving the configuration for the local (laptop) environment.
- `application-dev.properties` is saving the configuration for the remote development environment.
- `application-prod.properties` is saving the configuration for the remote production environment.

I have then the following Maven profiles defined in my `pom.xml`:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            ...
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            ...
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            ...
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then in my code I use this code to read the property file:

```
String rootPath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
String appConfigPath = rootPath + "application.properties";
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream(appConfigPath));
```

How can I adjust the code such that using a different Maven profile, a different property file is read?

Comment: Is this a spring boot application? The properties files makes it seem like it is but how you read the properties says otherwise. Would like to know so I can tailer my answer.

Comment: What is maven doing with the properties? Is it producing a file?

Comment: @Jason: the project is just *plain* Java. i.e. no Spring (and nowadays Spring polluted the entire Google results)

Comment: @ernest_k I have several property files and all are bundled in the jar and, similar with how Spring works, I also want to select at runtime one of the multiple property files. So I assume I need to have Maven pass some java command line arguments that later are read from the code

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Is your application being started by maven? In that case shouldn't maven just pass a command line argument, like the profile name and your code would pick the file based on a mapping or just `rootPath + System.getProperty("config.file")`? This of course can be done with a system property passed to java (`java -Dconfig.file=application-dev.properties -jar myjar.jar`)

Comment: @ernest_k To run the tests I am executing `mvn package`. And this will run also parts of the code that require some property files. I would have to link the Maven active profiles (`-P`) with different property files at runtime. Your suggestion goes into the right direction. Now I have to make Maven pass the `config.file` argument when executing java.